# Java regex for identifiers (letters, digits and underscores)

Tags: java, regex, string

Let's say you have given an input which could look like this `(identifier1 identifier_2 23 4)`.

I want to add a `#` symbol after every identifier, which can contain letters, digits and underscores. They can only start with a letter followed by variations of letters, digits and underscores. My approach was something like this:

```
input.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9_]+", "$0#");
```

However, this also puts `#` symbols after every single digit which I wanted to exclude. The result should be `(identifier1# identifier_2# 23 4)`. Is it possible to solve this problem with regex?

Comment: Doesn't it [work as expected](https://regex101.com/r/bL7kJ8/1)? You mean, no `#` should appear after `23` and `4`?

Comment: I only want to put `#` symbols after identifiers but not after digits. So it should be (identifier1# identifier_2# 23 4)

Comment: I think `\b(?!\d+\b)[A-Za-z0-9_]+\b` can help. But it will not exclude strings like `_____`. To exclude thiose, you can further restrict with `\b(?!_+\b|\d+\b)[A-Za-z0-9_]+\b`. Or even [`\b(?!\d+\b)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9])*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/bL7kJ8/2).

Comment: I assume that the parenthesis are not part of your input - if they are, then additional rules are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current regex says

> one or more upper or lower-case letters, digits, or underscores, in
>   whatever order.

According to that regex, `54` is a valid identifier.

You actually wanted to write

> a letter, followed by any number of letters, digits or
>   underscores, in whatever order

That would be written in code as:

```
input.replaceAll("[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*", "$0#");
```

---

Wiktor notes that this regex will still match "identifiers" that are inside something that is not identifier-ish. To solve this, you could use the following variation:

```
input.replaceAll("\\b([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\\b", "$1#")
```

This rejects `123ab123` as a valid identifier, but accepts `ab123` in `123 ab123`

Comment: This will match `A______`. Is it allowed? Also, this regex will match `A_B` inside `%%%%%%%A_B^^^^^`. Or it will find `z456` in `34z456,,,`

Comment: According to the OP's post, yes: "start with a letter followed by variations of letters, digits and underscores"

Comment: No, as you see, it will even find a match if a string starts with a digit. Anything.

Comment: Wiktor is right here, word boundaries or other delimiters would be needed to remove those cases.

Comment: Hopefully addressed in latest edit - thanks Wiktor, I had not noticed.

Comment: It will match `_________________` strings. Is it a valid identifier?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, that was a stray '_' that I removed in the first version but not in the improved, boundary-checking version. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Anyway, `$` must be supported since they are valid identifier symbols. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

## UPDATE 2

The [*Incremental Java*](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Eclin/MoreJava/Intro/var-ident.html) says:

> - Each identifier must have at least one character.
> - The first character must be picked from: alpha, underscore, or dollar sign. The first character can not be a digit.
> - The rest of the characters (besides the first) can be from: alpha, digit, underscore, or dollar sign. In other words, it can be any valid identifier character.
>   Put simply, an identifier is one or more characters selected from alpha, digit, underscore, or dollar sign. The only restriction is the first character can't be a digit.

So, you'd better use

```
String pattern = "(?:\\b[_a-zA-Z]|\\B\\$)[_$a-zA-Z0-9]*+";
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ6sD4/1)

## UPDATE

Acc. to [*Representing identifiers using Regular Expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953861/representing-identifiers-using-regular-expression), the  identifier regex is `[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*`.

So, you may use

```
String pattern = "\\b[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\\b";
```

**NOTE** that it allows `_______`.

You can use

```
String p = "\\b_*[a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\\b";
```

To avoid that. See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/kjqpgl).

```
String s = "(identifier1 identifier_2 23 4) ____ 33"; 
String p = "\\b_*[a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\\b";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(p, "$0#"));
```

Output: `(identifier1# identifier_2# 23 4) ____ 33`

## OLD ANSWER

You can use the following pattern:

```
String p = "\\b(?!\\d+\\b)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\\b";
```

Or (if a `_` can appear at the end):

```
String p = "\\b(?!\\d+\\b)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]*)*\\b";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL7kJ8/3)

The pattern requires that the whole word (as the expression is enclosed with word boundaries `\b`) should not be equal to a number (it is checked with `(?!\d+\b)`), and the unrolled part `[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9])*` matches non-underscore word character chunks that are followed by zero or more sequences of an underscore followed with non-underscore word character chunks.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/YSVXEn):

```
String s = "(identifier1 identifier_2 23 4) ____ 33"; 
String p = "\\b(?!\\d+\\b)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]*)*\\b";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(p, "$0#"));
```

Output: `(identifier1# identifier_2# 23 4) ____ 33`

Comment: That expression seems rather complex for what is required. `(?i)[a-z_]\w*` should be sufficient (or equivalents as posted in other answers/comments).

Comment: No idea what exactly is required. I suggest alternatives. Should the input end with `_` or not? I suggest a solution to that, too.

Comment: However, if two regular expressions are equivalent, then the shortest, or most understandable, should be preferred.

Comment: They are not equivalent.

Comment: No they are not but probably achieve the same goal. Why check if it's a number if the requirement for `[a-zA-Z]` at the start already rules out that option?

Comment: I have no test cases to check. If you prove these regexps work the same, I will agree it is useless. Right now, as I said, it is an **alternative**.

Comment: The OP did not mention "valid Java identifiers" as a goal. If that were the goal, then the question should be edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use java to read java, java's got you covered:
`"\\b\\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*\\b"`